# Sudo apt-get-repository: command not found

Tags: git, ubuntu, sudo, apt-get, apt

I am trying to add a repository in Ubuntu Mate using this command-

```
sudo apt-get-repository "****************(repository name)"
```

But i am having this output-

```
sudo: apt-get-repository: command not found
```

I have tried this-

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

and also this-

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

But still getting same **command not found** output.

What is the reason behind this? And also how can i solve this?

Comment: have you tried to update your repository? like  sudo apt-get update

Comment: I have updated with sudo apt-get update a few minutes ago. It is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should try

sudo add-apt-repository "(repository name)"

Comment: Thank you, it has worked. :)   Any reason behind my previous command didn't work?

Comment: Perhaps, because you have used the wrong command ?You used sudo apt-get-repository instead of add-apt-repository

Comment: oops, sorry i didn't see that. It was a typo. Got habituated in apt-get for a while.

Comment: Thank you. Searched for a while before I found something that worked in liue of `sudo add-apt` on its own

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminGuttmann , Even 8 years in the future it seems people (like me) just can't read :-)